# How to grant admin admin role?

Tags: admin, marklogic

I got this error:

```
SEC-NOADMIN: (err:FOER0000) User does not have admin role.
in /MarkLogic/security.xqy, at 6875:7, in sec:check-admin() [1.0-ml]
in /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/status-check.xqy, at 27:2, in adlib:status-check() [1.0-ml]
in /, at 6:0 [1.0-ml]
```

How can I grant admin role back to admin user?

Answer (score 2):

A user who has the Admin role can grant it either through the Admin UI, or using the [sec:user-add-roles](https://docs.marklogic.com/sec:user-add-roles) command.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security" at 
    "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";

sec:user-add-roles("Jim", ("admin"))
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. Neither Query Console nor Admin UI is accessible.  REST API wouldn't work as the authentication will fail.

Comment: @FionaChen You can assign the admin role to as many users as you wish. Best practice suggests that there be an admin account, but users should have their own accounts with assigned admin privileges. This is to provide accountability, ensuring that actions can be associated with a particular user.  If you don't have another admin user, then you should restore you Security database from backups.

Answer (score 0):

Michael:  I manage to restore the database. As such I create backup super user to mitigate risks. I appreciate your prompt attention!